# How to add TabbedPage inside ContentPage in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried to add **TabbedPage** inside a content Page so it's not showing any UI.
I also tried to find a solution but I get: we can't put TabbedPage inside a ContentPage
TabbedPage view should be a parent view.

[There are two tab inside a ContentPage i want to replace it with TabbedPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAXmO.png)

but i have such requirement to add Hi, I tried to add TabbedPage inside a content Page so it's not showing any UI.
I also tried to find solution but i get we cant put TabbedPage inside a ContentPage
TabbedPage view should be parent view

but i have such requirement to add TabbedPage in place of Recent and All. If any one have any idea please let me update.

Comment: Please read your own question once before posting

Comment: Have you got your answer? Please let us know. I am also working on same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XAML this can be an useful example for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             xmlns:me="clr-namespace:TabPages;assembly=TabPages"
             x:Class="YourApp.YourPage" BarBackgroundColor="#FF0000">
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 1">
        <StackLayout Padding="4">
            <!-- Content of the first tab -->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 2">
        <StackLayout Padding="4">
            <!-- Content of the second tab -->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I want to add TabbedPage  inside ContentPage

Comment: You have to change "ContentPage" with "TappedPage".

Answer (score -1):

It's difficult to understand your question. I have not a good English and I think not to have understand your problem.

BTW, it's not possible to add TabbedPage to a ContentPage. You have to add ContentPage to TabbedPage.

For Example (From Xamarin Docs)

```
public class MainPageCS : TabbedPage {   public MainPageCS ()   {
    var navigationPage = new NavigationPage (new SchedulePageCS ());
    navigationPage.Icon = "schedule.png";
    navigationPage.Title = "Schedule";

    Children.Add (new TodayPageCS ());
    Children.Add (navigationPage);   } }
```

The TabbedPage is populated with two child Page objects. The first child is a ContentPage instance, and the second tab is a NavigationPage containing a ContentPage instance.